# Python Class __init__ with csv input?

Tags: python

Suppose I define a class in Python and it looks like this.

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as read_obj:
            csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
            header = next(csv_reader)
            if header != None:
                for row in csv_reader:
                    self.a = row[0]
                    self.b = row[1]
```

How should I change the `__init__` so that when passing in a csv file with multiple rows, it will generate myclass object containing information from all rows?

For example, my test.csv file looks like this:

```
['a1','b1']
['a2','b2']
```

Then when I call it:
`mc = myclass('test.csv')`
mc will contain self.a = ['a1','a2'] and self.b = ['b1','b2']

Comment: that looks closer to [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.org/) format rather than CSV.  here's a package that's useful https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or just do it yourself with the standard `json` module

Answer (score 0):

Those attributes should be lists, and then you append to them in the loop.

```
class myclass:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.a = []
        self.b = []
        with open(filename, 'r') as read_obj:
            csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
            header = next(csv_reader)
            if header != None:
                for row in csv_reader:
                    self.a.append(row[0])
                    self.b.append(row[1])
```